# How to auto-fill content in a column until you come across a change. you end with the word “Stop” in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code that dynamically populates the numbers in the column that contains the word "Apple".

Search for the word in row 2: Apple. (This is how you find the column in which the data is.)
Then, in the column where "Apple" is located, check the numbers 0 to X 0 ........ 1 ...... 3 ...... 4 ..... 5 ..... X (irregularly). There are blank rows between the numbers.
Copy each number until the number changes. Start at 0.
Paste the result into the rov below.
Repeat until you find the word "Stop" in the column

The result should be in the column

A:BM are the columns in which to search.
The word "Apple" is in row 2, but I don't know where. Therefore, the column that contains the data must be searched first.
Here's an example of finding the word Apple in column "C"
Then it search for numbers vertically. If it searches for 0 in our case C4, then it adds another 0 below 0, and continues down until it finds 1. After searching for 1, it adds 1 below and repeats until it finds the word "Stop" in the last row.

```
     Before             After
     A B C              A B C
1    - - Apple      1   - - Apple
2    - - -          2   - - -
3    - - -          3   - - -
4    - - 0          4   - - 0 
5    - - -          5   - - 0
6    - - 1          6   - - 1
7    - - -          7   - - 1
8    - - -          8   - - 1
9    - - 2          9   - - 2
10   - - -          10  - - 2
11   - - -          11  - - 2
12   - - -          12  - - 2
13   - - 3          13  - - 3
14   - - -          14  - - 3
15   - - 4          15  - - 4
16   - - -          16  - - 4
17   - - -          17  - - 4
18   - - -          18  - - 4
19   - - -          19  - - 4
20   - - 5          20  - - 5
21   - - 6          21  - - 6
22   - - -          22  - - 6
23   - - Stop       23  - - Stop
24   - - -          24  - - -
25   - - -          25  - - -
```

I don't know how to start. Please for any help.
This code (does not work). I'm testing how it should be. It's just a construction. Finally, I want to add code for the others in this great forum. I ask the admin not to close the question to me if I don't explain it enough, because I'm lost in macros.

```
Sub Macro5()

'1. Select Workbook 
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
'2 Select a column
Columns("C:C").Select
'3 Search Word "Apple"
Vlookup?
'Look up the number 0 in this column
Selection.Copy
' Paste the copied cell below                 
Loop
' (continue copying the number below.)         
If Columns("XY:YX").Value = "Stop" Then
End If
End Sub
```

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this where the column will only run on the first instance of finding Apple in row 2. If you need to change this row, change where I've commented.

```
Sub test()
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim Num As String
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim Col As String
Dim ColChecker As Boolean

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sh = Wb.Sheets(1)

iCol = 1
Do While ColChecker = False
    If Sh.Cells(2, iCol).Value = "Apple" Then 'change the 2 here [row number]
        ColChecker = True
        Col = Split(Cells(1, iCol).Address, "$")(1)
    End If
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop

i = 3 'change the 3 here [row number]
Num = ""
Do While Sh.Range(Col & i).Value <> "Stop" and i < 300 'and the row is less than 300
    If Sh.Range(Col & i).Value = "" Or Sh.Range(Col & i).Value = "-" Then
        Sh.Range(Col & i).Value = Num
    ElseIf Sh.Range(Col & i).Value <> "Stop" And Sh.Range(Col & i).Value <> "" And Sh.Range(Col & i).Value <> "-" And Sh.Range(Col & i).Value <> "Apple" Then
        Num = Sh.Range(Col & i).Value
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. It works exactly as I needed it. I'm still thinking about how to add "Stop" when it exceeds line 300. Because if I forget to put a stop manually, then it goes on.

Comment: Really glad it works. Use the ```i``` in the ```do while``` to have ```and i < 300```

Comment: Yes, it works just as well.
I automatically added a "stop" to the bottom by creating an auxiliary macro that adds a "stop" below the table. Then it stops even earlier. I couldn't find a way to stop the macro when it gets below the level of the last row of the table :)